# Bind to @Output Observable instead of callback?

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have a slider component that emits numbers while you drag the slider, which is usable like so: `<my-slider (change)="onSlide($event)"></my-slider>`. I'd like to get rid of the `onSlide` method and instead bind the `change` event stream to an `Observable<number>` property (instead of a callback).

I am using an Angular 2 `EventEmitter` for my `@Output`. `EventEmitter` inherits from a RxJs `Subject`, which is an `Observable` and an `Observer`. I wish to reuse the `Observable` side of the `EventEmitter`.

Of course I can push values that enter through `onSlide` onto another `Subject`, but I wish to prevent this boilerplate and overhead. Is there a way?

Comment: You can do `(change)="myOutput.emit($event)"`. Assuming that I understood you correctly.

Comment: That would save me the boilerplate of the callback (great). I would still have to copy from one subject to the next.

Comment: You could put your EventEmitter in a Service, have your component call an API/method on the service to trigger/`emit()` the event, and all subscribers will be notified.  So no copying. Here's [an example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34376854/delegation-eventemitter-in-angular2/34402436#34402436).

Comment: Nice idea, but this doesn't reduce boilerplate nor does it work with multiple components since services are singletons. Perhaps I could work something out, but that would break the angular api. I would prefer Eric's way, which doesn't cause much overhead anyway.

Comment: @LodewijkBogaards Did you find a better way to do this ? Without any boilerplate code or copy to different subject.

Comment: @AdrianFaciu nope, would have posted it here.

Comment: You could get your viewChildren of type MySlider and tie into the event output.  It would be difficult to know which slider is for what external value.  I guess you could pass an input identifier but that is getting ugly.

Answer (score 4):

Not sure if relevant or if it helps someone: I ran into a similar issue: I wanted to consume a property of type `Observable<number>` provided by a component in the parent component.

After reading [Observables and Reactive Programming in Angular 2](http://blog.rangle.io/observables-and-reactive-programming-in-angular-2/), I noticed that I need to "turn" around my architecture and let the parent create the `Observable` and then assign it to the child.

So instead of having a `MyComponent` with an `@Output()` of type `Observable<number>` (which was then initialized to `new BehaviorSubject(0)` and modified using calls to `next`), I changed `MyComponent` to haven an `@Input()` of type `BehaviorSubject<number>`:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-component',
  template: `
    <button (click)="increment()">Click me!</button>
  `,
})
export class MyComponent {
  private _count : number = 0;

  @Input()
  public counter : BehaviorSubject<number>;

  public increment() {
    this._count++;

    if (this.counter)
      this.counter.next(this._count);
  }
}
```

The parent now creates a BehaviorSubject and binds to the property. It can easily consume the BehaviorSubject as an Observable:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <my-component [counter]="count"></my-component>
    <span>{{text | async}}</span>
  `,
})
export class App {
  public text : Observable<string>;

  public count : BehaviorSubject<number> = new BehaviorSubject(0);

  constructor() {
    this.text = this.count.map(n => "Click: " + n);
  }
}
```

Plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/rKtVWmmGnFn4Po4B4CCL?p=preview

So in your case, I would say that your slider should provide an `@Input` (maybe call it value or number) and let the parent assign an observable (instead of letting the child create one).

Answer (score 1):

One of core difference between Angular 1 and Angular 2 is that change detection is always performed from top to bottom. That makes performance much better. Also there is no need to perform "stabilization" ($digest loop) as it was in Angular 1.

In Angular 2 you can't "push" change back in other way, except emitting event with `EventEmitter`/`Subject`, so Angular 2 can start checking component's Change Detectors.

[Here is nice](http://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/02/22/angular-2-change-detection-explained.html) article about this topic.